# How to upload an Image to cloudinary from ionic capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, upload, capacitor, cloudinary

I am developing an application that contains a form which consists of two inputs (strings) and an image, I am using ionic 6 with a capacitor and I get the image from the capacitor camera plugin, which is not a File type, I don't know how i can upload the image to cloudinary, no need to store the image on the user's device, just on the cloudinary server.
assuming that the capacitor plugin will return a value type of any of these 3 types:

```
CameraResultType​:

uri = 'uri'

base64 = 'base64'

DataUrl = 'dataUrl'
```

Here I get the image that I select from the capacitor camera plugin.

```
// Gallery option
async getPicture() {
  const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    source: CameraSource.Photos,
    promptLabelHeader: 'Subir Imagen',
    promptLabelPhoto: 'Galeria',
    promptLabelCancel: 'Cancelar',
    correctOrientation: true,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
  });
  console.log('image:', image);
}
// FIN Gallery option
```

[the type of data I get from the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHEMu.png)

Be able to upload images to cloudinary through ionic 6 camera plugin capacitor

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this Capacitor Cloudinary plugin: https://capawesome.io/plugins/cloudinary/

```js
import { Camera, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/camera';
import { Cloudinary, ResourceType } from '@capawesome/capacitor-cloudinary';

async getAndUploadPicture() {
  const result = await Camera.getPhoto({
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
  });
  await Cloudinary.uploadResource({
    path: result.path,
    publicId: 'my_public_id',
    resourceType: ResourceType.image,
    uploadPreset: 'my_preset',
  });
}
```